# HTTP POST response into webview doesn't work fine

Tags: android, webview, http-post

I've tried this example and it works fine with the example URL (`http://search.yahoo.com/search`), but when I do it for "http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?target=&client_id=docu", I can't see the response in webview correctly. I mean, all text is visible, but the images are not. And links don't work.

How do I fix this problem?

```
public class ilias extends Activity {
    WebView webView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?client_id=docu");
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "stacked"));  //This username
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "overflow")); //works.
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

            Toast.makeText(ilias.this,
              "Finished",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String webData = stringBuffer.toString();

            webData = webData.replace("#", "%23");
            webData = webData.replace("%", "%25");
            webData = webData.replace("\\", "%27");
            webData = webData.replace("?", "%3f");

            webView.loadData(webData,
              "text/html",
              "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(ilias.this,
                           e.toString(),
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(ilias.this,
                           e.toString(),
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        finally{
            if (bufferedReader != null){
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've got: http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/4913/deviceyl.png, and this is what I want: http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/8591/device1g.png

Comment: Try posting your code for us to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got to use
`loadDataWithBaseURl("http://www.ilias.de/docu/",webData,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");`
instead of
`webView.loadData(webData, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

The "simple" loadData method does not load content from the network, according to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

@@@@@@@ EDIT @@@@@@@

In order to see the page just like in the native browser, first remove these lines:

```
   webData = webData.replace("#", "%23");
   webData = webData.replace("%", "%25");
   webData = webData.replace("\\", "%27");
   webData = webData.replace("?", "%3f");
```

This is because, either I'm not understanding the API documentation  or the loadDataWithBaseUrl does't not decode the characters back.

And play around with the zoom level (you can do that programmatically)

Regards
[image]

Comment: this works better, but i continue without see webpage as in native explorer or pc internet explorer.

Comment: @AlexxPerez can you be more specific?

Comment: I do not see the page as the original, but looks a bit equal. I need to see it as original please. You can test the code, username and password works. Just add webview to main.xml and permission internet and you will see.

Comment: In addition when I click a link it does not recognize me as logged

Comment: Hi @AlexxPerez, that is a different issue, the screenshot you see is what i got doing what I wrote, I think that was the main question... To keep the credentials I guess you should set a custom WebViewClient and override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`. I think you should solve the first issue doing what I wrote, think about a workaround, and make a new question in case you are not able to solve it.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, it should. Maybe because im using MyHttpClient instead of DefaultHttpClient because is https page, with my certificate stored on mykeystore.bks

Comment: only remains for me to keep the credentials to navigate properly

Comment: @AlexxPerez, in order to contribute to the community, I suggest you to start a new question with the new issue you want to solve. The best way to say "thank you" in StackOverflow is to **accept** the answer and/or **vote** positively. Read more about it in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), and welcome to StackOverflow.